# Converting a thread id in a Docker cgroup to the host thread id

Tags: linux, docker, process, cgroups, linux-namespaces

Is there any straightforward way to map a cgroups thread id to the host thread id, assuming I know the `$CONTAINER_PARENT_PROCESSID` and its corresponding `$HOST_PARENT_PROCESSID`.

The thread id in the container is part of the output of `ps -T $CONTAINER_PARENT_PROCESSID` and the thread id in the host is part of the output of `ps -T $HOST_PARENT_PROCESSID`.